# Hover function loops infinitly in plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, position

I am making a simple plugin in which if i hover over an image its background color should change to semi-transparent black.

For that I have placed a tag above it with class name `overlay` to give the effect. Since height and width will be different for each image, I am taking the height/width from the image and dynamically giving it to `overlay` class. In the end when mouse goes out I am simply making background color transparent.

Here's the code

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<a href="" class="box">
    <img src="http://www.cars.co.za/images/specials/ncs-red-renault.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

```js
(function($) {    
    $.fn.imageOverlay = function() {
        return this.each(function() {                
            var $this = $(this);
            var width = $this.width();
            var height = $this.height();            

            $this.hover(function(){
                $('.overlay').css({
                   width: width,
                   height: height,
                   backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'    
                });
                console.log('in');
            }, function(){
                $('.overlay').css({
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                });
                console.log('out');
            });                
        });
    }    
}(jQuery));

(function($){        
    $('.box').imageOverlay();        
}(jQuery));

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is working but not as it should be when in and out starts and never stops; kind of going in loop.

Are there any solutions to this? Or is there a correct way to implement the same functionality as a plugin?

Comment: check if this works https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/hkd4fgkh/

Comment: no its not same problem infinite loop

Comment: here's an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hkd4fgkh/2/

Comment: Sam, try this https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/hkd4fgkh/3/

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need to have a plugin for this

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.box .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.box:hover .overlay {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://www.cars.co.za/images/specials/ncs-red-renault.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
```

---

If you want jQuery plugin

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.imageOverlay = function() {
    return this.each(function() {

      var $this = $(this),
        $overlay = $this.find('.overlay');

      $this.hover(function() {
        $overlay.show();
      }, function() {
        $overlay.hide();
      });

    });
  }

}(jQuery));


(function($) {

  $('.box').imageOverlay();

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.box .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.box:hover .overlay {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://www.cars.co.za/images/specials/ncs-red-renault.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: i have edited my question where am giving .overlay position: absolute and display: inline block if you do that you will understand what i am trying to say.

Comment: hello sir this is not a jquery solution its a css hack i had tried it already. Let take a scenario where this image is to be used on every mobile platform width. and for example it has a width of 500px and height of 500px. Now if you take this image on mobile screen where width is 768px your overlay class will display on complete 768px screen giving a white space of 268px with only semi transparent black background. Since image width is 500px only .This was the reason behind this plugin development. I hope you get my point

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/hkd4fgkh/4/)

HTML code

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img src="http://www.cars.co.za/images/specials/ncs-red-renault.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

JS code

```
(function($){

    $.fn.imageOverlay = function(){
        return this.each(function(){

            var $this = $(this);
            var width = $this.find("img").width();
            var height = $this.find("img").height();            

            $this.hover(function(){
                $this.find('.overlay').css({
                   width: width,
                   height: height,
                   backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'    
                });
                console.log('in');
            }, function(){
                $this.find('.overlay').css({
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                });
                console.log('out');
            });

        });
    }

}(jQuery));


(function($){

    $('.box').imageOverlay();

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really looking for a jQuery only solution, then you can look at a timer based solution like

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.imageOverlay = function() {
    return this.each(function() {

      var $this = $(this),
        $overlay = $this.find('.overlay'),
        $img = $this.find("img"),
        timer;

      $img.hover(function() {
        var width = $img.width();
        var height = $img.height();
        $overlay.css({
          width: width,
          height: height
        }).show();
      }, function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
          $overlay.hide();
        }, 200);
      });

      $overlay.hover(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }, function() {
        $overlay.hide();
      });

    });
  }

}(jQuery));


(function($) {

  $('.box').imageOverlay();

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <a href="">
    <img src="http://www.cars.co.za/images/specials/ncs-red-renault.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
```